# How to show time next to the command line in terminal/console

Tags: linux, shell

When I execute command line (linux) I want to know what time there were executed when I scroll up my terminal window. I saw this once setup in linux environment but how to do that?

[image: Time before command line]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set your prompt variable (`PS1`). Something like the following should get you going:

```
<~/temp>$ export PS1="[\$(date +%k:%M)]> "
[12:16]>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted. How to make it permanent? when I log back in I want to have that already exported?

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike You're welcome. To make it permanent, add it to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` files. Once done, source the file or log out and log back in.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup `PS1` to always show current time in BASH;

```
export PS1='\A-\w>'
```

- `\A` - current time stamp without seconds part
- `\t` - current time stamp with seconds
- `\w` - current directory

Comment: It appears `\A` would be more to the liking of the OP.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman: I edited with both options in comments.

Answer (score 3):

1) Open bashrc file

```
gedit ~\.bashrc
```

2) Find the following text:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] :\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

3) And replace with:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\] [\d|\t]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

4) Restart terminal to check.

[Sample output in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqyb4.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you would love to show it in the below format:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS {domain}@{userId}:~/{folder1}/{folder2}$`

```
export PS1='\D{%F %T} \$\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have my terminal with this configuration:

[hh:mm:ss] PC@User:~$

This can be achieved putting the following instruction on file ~/.bashrc

export PS1="[\$(date +%k:%M:%S)] [\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ "

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

more simple solution

```
export PS1='\D{%F %T} \u@\h:\W\$'
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.